# Can we use the result of one select query as if condition to find the records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

first i have to find the agent name from enquiry table if agent name find then if part will wrk n if agent name not found the 2nd query dat is else part will work. Below is my query plz let me know where im wrong. Thanks in advance

```
create proc ConfirmationMail_ToAgent
(
    @Enquiry_Id nvarchar(50)
)
as
begin
    select Agent_Name from Enquiry where Enquiry_Id = @Enquiry_Id as jh
    if(jh != 'Select')
    begin
        select e.Agent_Name,e.Agent_Email,e.Client_Name,e.Handled_By,ef.EMail_Id from Enquiry e inner join Employee_FullDetail ef on e.Handled_By = ef.First_Name where e.Enquiry_Id = @Enquiry_Id
    end
    else
    begin
       select e.Client_Name,e.Client_Address,e.Handled_By,ef.EMail_Id from Enquiry e inner join Employee_FullDetail ef on e.Handled_By = ef.First_Name where e.Enquiry_Id = @Enquiry_Id
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SQL Server`, you assign the column into a variable using following syntax

```
DECLARE @Var varchar(xx)
SELECT @Var = [ColName] FROM [TableName]
```

So your query should look like:

```
create proc ConfirmationMail_ToAgent
(
@Enquiry_Id nvarchar(50)
)
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE @jh VARCHAR(100)
    select @jh= Agent_Name from Enquiry where Enquiry_Id = @Enquiry_Id 
    if(@jh != 'Select')
    begin
        select e.Agent_Name,e.Agent_Email,e.Client_Name,e.Handled_By,ef.EMail_Id from Enquiry e inner join Employee_FullDetail ef on e.Handled_By = ef.First_Name where e.Enquiry_Id = @Enquiry_Id
    end
    else
    begin
        select e.Client_Name,e.Client_Address,e.Handled_By,ef.EMail_Id from Enquiry e inner join Employee_FullDetail ef on e.Handled_By = ef.First_Name where e.Enquiry_Id = @Enquiry_Id
    end
end
```

Comment: and did you check that the @jh does sometimes get value `Select`. I suggest you inserting `select @jh as jh` just before `if(...` to check it gets the `Select`

Comment: nw the query wrks but why this query returning the same value twice

Comment: what do you mean? are you sending different values each time and the Agent_Name is diferent?

Comment: no this is procedure execution exec  ConfirmationMail_ToAgent 'RH - 02/09/2013 - 2'
and below is the result appear

Comment: no this is procedure execution exec  ConfirmationMail_ToAgent 'RH - 02/09/2013 - 2'
and below is the result appear   Ish Travels packages@ishtravels.com Shiv Paul paul@roverholidays.com
Ish Travels packages@ishtravels.com Shiv Paul paul@roverholidays.com

Comment: if you execute the SP with the same params every time, don't expect different results.

Comment: do you expect to see `Select` in a column of the table `Enquiry`

Comment: im executing the procedure for once n it shows me the record for twice instead of 1record

Comment: It doesn't make any sense, please edit your question adding a the SP as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Well I really think you have to read about [DRY principle in programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Please follow this principle and it'll help you to maintain your code in the future. It looks you don't need 2 queries here, you can just use one:

```
create proc ConfirmationMail_ToAgent
(
     @Enquiry_Id nvarchar(50)
)
as
begin
    select
        case when e.Agent_Name != 'Select' then e.Agent_Name else e.Client_Name end as Name,
        case when e.Agent_Name != 'Select' then e.Agent_Email else e.Client_Address end as Address,
        e.Handled_By, ef.EMail_Id
    from Enquiry as e
        inner join Employee_FullDetail as ef on ef.First_Name = e.Handled_By
    where e.Enquiry_Id = @Enquiry_Id
end
```

This one will be **easier to maintain** - if you have to add columns to resultset, you do it just once, **easier to read** - you don't have to think about - what's the difference in these 2 queries?
To completely follow DRY principle, this query could be rewritten, for example, like this:

```
create proc ConfirmationMail_ToAgent
(
     @Enquiry_Id nvarchar(50)
)
as
begin
    select
        C.Name, C.Email,
        e.Client_Name, e.Handled_By, ef.EMail_Id
    from Enquiry as e
        inner join Employee_FullDetail as ef on ef.First_Name = e.Handled_By
        outer apply ( 
            select e.Agent_Name, e.Agent_Email where e.Agent_Name != 'Select' union all
            select e.Client_Name, e.Client_Address where e.Agent_Name == 'Select'
        ) as C(Name, Email)
    where e.Enquiry_Id = @Enquiry_Id
end
```

Comment: tHE ABOVE query is working with where condition but what to do if i want the same query without any where condition means i want to search each record if i get agentname then the result will be agentname and if i get agentname as select or null the result will be client's name plz help me im solving the issue thx in advance for help